# If all the characters in the pattern string are unique/different, then how KMP take O(m+n)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

For example:

Source String is: "Mac and Jack are friends"
Pattern String is : "are".

So that it looks like that always a matching of pattern will start from 0th index.
and in the source string will move character by character.

So it seems like it should have the complexity of O(m*n).
In general I can say that KMP should have worst case complexity of O(m*n), but I read that using KMP we can solve subtring matching algorithm in O(m+n), So curious to know abt that worst case analysis.

Comment: That's the best case for KMP when all characters are unique, it would be at most 1 "jump" for each character of the text

Comment: Reference : [String Algorithms Stanford](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs97si/10-string-algorithms.pdf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the worst case complexity for KMP when the goal is to find all occurrences of a certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182651/whats-the-worst-case-complexity-for-kmp-when-the-goal-is-to-find-all-occurrence)

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this a lot as well. Here's what I've concluded. (Let's say `n` is the length of the string to search and `m` is the length of the pattern)

In the naive brute force solution of string matching, the only reason you need to iterate over all `n` for a given `m` is if there are repeats

For example:

```
string: abcdabcdabcd
pattern:abcde
```

Iteration 1:

```
string: abcdabcdabcd
        ^
pattern:abcde
        ^
```

Iteration m

```
string: abcdabcdabcd
            ^
pattern:abcde
            ^
```

mismatch! so on iteration `m+1`, we do:

```
string: abcdabcdabcd
         ^
pattern:abcde
        ^
```

Now in the case of KMP, on iteration `m+1`, we don't need to reset the string pointer so far back because because if the character at position 2 on the string (1-based indexing) did indeed match the pattern, then the pattern would have duplicate characters in a row.

```
KMP iteration m + 1, pattern has all distinct characters

string: abcdabcdabcd
            ^
pattern:abcde
        ^
```

If there are repeats, then on iteration `m+1`, then we don't reset the pointer on the pattern as far:

```
KMP iteration m + 1, pattern has runs of characters

string: aaaac
            ^
pattern:aaaab
           ^
```